# How to filter out values with 0 has_and_belongs_to_many relationships?

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I have two `documents`

```rb
class Tag
  # ...
  store_in collection: :tags
  has_and_belongs_to_many :offices, class_name: 'Office'
end

class Office
  # ...
  store_in collection: :offices
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags, class_name: 'Tag'
end
```

all tags `_id`'s are stored in an array in the `offices` collection in `mongodb`

in the following query, I need to filter out any tags that do not exist on any offices, my first instinct was to convert the `Tag.all` response to an array, and then filter out values manually.
I do not think this is not possible because I use [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari) for REST API pagination.

```rb
## ...

tags = Tag.all

## need to filter out tags with tag.offices.count.zero?
## ...

return tags.page(n).per(25)
```

Comment: `Tag.where(office_ids: {'$size'=>0})`

Comment: unfortunately the model doesnt save `office_ids` to `Tag`, id's of tags are stored on the office @D.SM

Comment: How is it that office ids are not stored on tags?

Comment: @D.SM I believe autosave would need to be turned on within office's `has_and_belongs_to_many` in order to update the tags record when creating/updating an office

Comment: Do you have a documentation reference for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could do `tags = Tag.joins(:offices)`. This will do an INNER JOIN and will only return the tags that has offices associated with them.

Comment: I believe this is supported in newer versions of mongoid, I am using `6.4`